# php mail form security: most reliable way to spot new lines

Tags: preg-match, newline, php

I am trying to build a secure php contact form to allow users (and hopefully not spammers) to send mail.

I am looking at the way of detecting new lines in the from: field, with which users will submit their email address and in the subject: field.

I have 2 alternatives aof the same function to detect new lines and I would like your opinion about which one would be the most reliable (meaning working in the most cases):

```
function containingnewlines1($stringtotest) {
    if (preg_match("/(%0A|%0D|\\n+|\\r+)/i", $stringtotest) != 0) {
        echo "Newline found. Suspected injection attempt";
        exit;
    }
}

function containingnewlines2($stringtotest) {
    if (preg_match("/^\R$/", $stringtotest) != 0) {
        echo "Newline found. Suspected injection attempt";
        exit;
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for your opinions!

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The vastly more pertinent question is "Which one is more reliable?".  The efficiency of either approach is irrelevant because neither approach should take more than a few milliseconds to execute.  Trying to decide between the two based on a matter of milliseconds is a [micro-optimization](/questions/tagged/micro-optimization).

Furthermore, what do you mean by efficiency?  Do you mean which one is faster?  Which one consumes the least memory?  Efficiency is an ill-defined term, you need to be more specific.

If you absolutely must make a decision based on performance/efficiency requirements then I'd recommend constructing a benchmark and finding out for yourself which one is the closest fit to your requirements, because at the end of the day only you can answer that question.

Comment: Thank you very much, I edited the question as I actually meant, as you correctly suggested, "which one is the more reliable"

Answer (score 0):

I added myself 2 more funcs and did a benchmark of `100000` loops:

```
function containingnewlines3($stringtotest) {
   return (strpbrk($stringtotest,"\r\n") !== FALSE);
}

function containingnewlines4($stringtotest) {
   return (strpos($stringtotest,"\n") !== FALSE && strpos($stringtotest,"\r\n") !== FALSE);
}

$start = microtime(TRUE);
for($x=0;$x<100000;$x++) {
   containingnewlines1($html);   // 0.272623 ms
   containingnewlines2($html);   // 0.244299 ms
   containingnewlines3($html);   // 0.377767 ms
   containingnewlines4($html);   // 0.142282 ms
}
echo (microtime(TRUE) - $start);
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. But I was wondering which way gets me to spot the bridest range of new lines (depending on the OS)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I decided to use the first function, as it covers 2 more cases (%OA and %OD) and as it also includes all the new lines characters variations used by different OSes (\n, \n\r etc).